# Problema con consola de linux

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bash, consola

Estoy intentando acceder a una carpeta de mi escritorio que contiene la llave para establecer la conexión ssh con la instancia de aws.

He instalado el bash ubuntu para mi sistema windows (ya que he visto que con la consola de windows no se puede hacer la conexión).

El problema está cuando quiero hacer cd a la carpeta de mi escritorio me aparece el mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pd: el directorio donde me encuentro una vez abro el bash es el siguiente:

```
mninety@Mario:~$ pwd
/home/mninety
```

Comment: ls :V  y veras que tas en c:/user/mario entonces solo dedes darle cd Desktop/keys

Comment: Tampoco me deja, me aparece el mismo mensaje de error

Comment: ok dale ls y luego le das solo le das cd Desktop es sensicble a mayusculas y minisculas

Comment: Tampoco. ls es para comprobar qué archivos hay dentro de una carpeta.

Comment: cd C:/Users/Mario/Desktop/keys  En la primera estás usando `\` en vez de `/` y en la segunda no pones el disco duro `C:`

Comment: Usualmente, las carpetas para usarios están en /home, o puede ser ~/Desktop

Comment: Si pongo /home me aparece lo siguiente:

mninety@Mario:~$ cd /home                                                                                               mninety@Mario:/home$ ls                                                                                                 mninety

Comment: Ha intentado ~/Escritorio ?

Answer (score 3):

Si estás usando WSL (alias, "Ubuntu Windows") tu partición C: se encuentra dentro de `/mnc/c/`

WSL simula (no es una máquina virtual) que estás en una máquina virtual y te recrea un ambiente a parte de tu instalación normal de Windows. Esta se ve como si estuviera montada dentro de esta simulación. No es un Ubuntu dentro de un Windows, es una simulación (no virtualización).

Entonces, para acceder a tu escritorio de Windows desde tu WSL tienes que hacerlo a la ruta completa con:

```
$cd /mnt/c/Users/mario/Desktop/keys
```

Como recomendación, puedes crear un alias para acceder a tu carpeta HOME desde tu WSL con:

```
$alias winhome='cd /mnt/c/Users/mario'
```

O crea un enlace simbólico desde tu HOME de Windows a una carpeta dentro de tu Usuario en tu WSL.

```
$ln -s /mnt/c/Users/mario ~/Documents/windows_home  #o como le quieras llamar.
```